# Python code to add and print output for a person selling same product to same store

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make a list of people based on quantity of books sold.

The data is provided in this file 1711.txt:

```
- > david book 05 walmart  
- > emily book 10 kroger  
- > jason food 11 target
- > david food 20 kroger
- > eva cloth 13 target
- > david book 5 walmart
```

The output should be something like :

> david sold 10 books to walmart
>   eva sold 13 cloths to target
>   david sold 20 food to kroger

Here is my code so far:

```
d = {}
p={}
q={}
with open("1711.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        a=line.split()
        l,m,n,o=str(a[0]), str(a[1]), int(a[2]), str(a[3])    
        if l not in d:
            d[l] = {}
        if m not in d[l]:
            d[l][m] = {}
        if n not in d[l]:
            d[l][m][n] = {}
        d[l][m][n]= str(o)

print(d)
```

That code generates this output:

```json
{
 'eva': {'cloth': {13: 'target'}}, 
 'david': {'book': {5: 'walmart'}, 'food': {20: 'kroger'}}, 
 'emily': {'book': {10: 'kroger'}}, 
 'jason': {'food': {11: 'target'}}
}
```

But it is not adding the values of the products sold to the same store by the same person. For example I am getting the output as:

> david book 5 walmart

whereas the required output is:

> david book 10 walmart

Comment: the code is required to run in python 3.5

Comment: Hi there; I have edited your question to make it a bit more readable. Remember, on this site you are encouraged to [edit] and re-edit your questions to improve them as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At no point are you trying to add values, so you will never get a total.
Your data structure looks difficult, perhaps a different structure would help, e.g. `{ name : { product { store : total }}}` would make it easier to add up the values.

```
a=line.split()
l,m,n,o=str(a[0]), str(a[1]), int(a[2]), str(a[3])
```

is unnecessary if there are only 4 items on each line as you can just unpack the tuples:

```
l, m, n, o = line.strip().split()
```

So taking this into account the code could look like:

```
d = {}
with open(...) as f:
    for line in f:
        l,m,n,o = line.strip().split()
        d.setdefault(l, {}).setdefault(m, {})
        d[l][m][o] = d[l][m].get(o, 0) + int(n)

for name, products in d.items():
    for product, stores in products.items():
        for store, total in stores.items():
            print('{} sold {} {} to {}'.format(name, total, product, store))
```

Output:

```
eva sold 13 cloth to target
jason sold 11 food to target
emily sold 10 book to kroger
david sold 10 book to walmart
david sold 20 food to kroger
```

Comment: Thank you so much!